# Setting "setprecision" correctly

Tags: c++, stl

Hi although I do something like this

```
 #include <iomanip>
...
        std::cout<<"Numbers "<<std::setprecision(2)<<numb1<< "  "<<std::setprecision(2)<<numb2<<" "<<std::setprecision(2)<<numb3<<"  "<< std::setprecision(4)<<numb4<<std::endl;
```

I do get

```
Numbers  14  1.5e+02 0.0053 & 220
```

How can I really make set the precision per column to get a consistent format and not this mixture of precision(5) and scientific format?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `std::fixed` manipulator too which will switch off any reversion to scientific notation:

```
std::cout << std::fixed /*<< as before from here*/
```

If you want to switch the scientific notation back on again, then introduce the manipulator `std::scientific`.

Reference; http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: it is ok if I have to specify the precision just before the number - the problem is that it does not work and print a mixture of scientific/pre(5) or prec(1) numbers...

Comment: Yes that's fine. You can introduce manipulators anywhere in the cout chain. Although to be honest, I think I'd plump for a sort of `sprintf`-type solution here.